# How to add whole screen under scroll view except footbar buttons

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I have a screen and many layouts items in it. I want to take whole screen under ScrollView except footer buttons so that in small screens if size decreases it would scroll down. But when i add ScrollView as a parent layout to all it either crashes saying "Scroll View cannot handle too many child items" or it would mess up layout. Any solution. Below is my code and screenshot

Please note in below code i am not putting everything under ScrollView but I want everything to come inside ScrollView except footer buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#E7EBEE"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#0a2436"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" >
        </ImageView>

        <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/formTab"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray" 
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingTop="0dip"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        </ScrollView>

        <!--  android:divider="@color/listDivider" -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#e7ebee"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:paddingBottom="7dip"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="SNS Connection"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#737577"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"

                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Facebook"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tokentextfacebook"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/facebook"   
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Your token is run out. Please reconnect"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:gravity="left"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

             <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/twitter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Twitter"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#4a82ae"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/twitter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tokentexttwitter"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/facebook"   
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Your token is run out. Please reconnect"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:gravity="left"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Activity"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Support"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Messages"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: List-view have own Scroller function, so why you need to add within ScrollView.

Comment: There's no need of using scroll view while using list view. Remove that and check

Comment: Reason being when i try same layout in smaller screens it eases out below part, so was thinking if we can get the same under scroll View. Also listview is static, has only 4 items

Comment: So there's no need of that .. U can create four layout for same.

Comment: Which part you want to add in scrollview ? @user45678

Comment: Here, you can add all the child layout into one FrameLayout and then add this frameLayout to scroll view.

Comment: @ManishPatel - Can you show an example in my code. Thanks

Comment: @user45678 actually i want to share my layout snap into here but it is exceed characters limits and not uploading all the layout snap.so would you give me your email.so i want to send layout snap into your email. If you don't mind. I just upload one image have look.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` because the `ListView` class implements its own scrolling and it just doesn't receive gestures because they all are handled by the parent `ScrollView`. I strongly recommend you to simplify your layout somehow. For example you can add views you want to be scrolled to the `ListView` as headers or footers.

If you want to add scrollview for your footer only then you can add your footer as view in your `ListView` only which will provide smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like that .. Make sure scroll view contains only one child .. check out my code and analyze it. Hope it sounds good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="center text"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@color/black" >
    </LinearLayout> 

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="center text"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@color/black" >
    </LinearLayout> 

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="center text"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@color/black" >
    </LinearLayout> 

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```